# Однородны ли сказуемые?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сказуемые

Предложение **"Подумай об этом и ответишь"** — односоставное опред-личн. или два односоставных опред-личн. (тогда нужна запятая перед "и")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подумай об этом, и ответишь.

Это два односоставных неоднородных (определенно-личных) предложения, запятая ставится. Они **неоднородны**, так как  так сказуемые имеют разную грамматическую форму.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй, да это однородные члены предложения: подумай, ответишь. Тут пропущен главный член предложения - ты, к которому относятся два сказуемых. Значит это предложение односоставное опред-личн.

Comment: У меня сомнение на этот счет. Не обязаны ли однородные сказуемые отвечать на один и тот же вопрос?

Comment: Однородные члены – это члены предложения, которые обычно отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и связаны с одним и тем же словом в предложении.

Comment: http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/723-27_odnorodnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html - это сайт, на котором все об однородных сказуемых.

Comment: "Подумай" и "ответишь" отвечают на разные вопросы. Так почему же Вы считаете их однородными членами?